# Nginx and SPAs (Angular)

Tags: angular, nginx, single-page-application

I have the following config for nginx:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location  /app {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

When running the container and going to `http://localhost:8000/app`
It works great, but if I navigate to some sub-route for example: `http://localhost:8000/app/products` (which is a valid route in the anuglar router) and then restarting I am getting nginx 404 error.

I think I have a problem in my nginx configuration. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the `try_files` line to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;`

That directive checks for the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing.

If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.
That should be your SPA app route.

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me at last:
`try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html?$args;`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where I added try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html to my Nginx configuration, but it didn't work as expected. I also tried try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html?$args;, but it still didn't resolve the problem. After investigating further, I discovered that I was modifying the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file, while Nginx was actually reading the configurations from **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**. For anyone facing the same issue, I have provided the working configuration below:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

I'm using Nginx in a Docker container as a web server for my Angular application.